# Issue in Image grid image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

The images is not resizing according to container. I have issue although i have set  both height and width 100% the image is not taking width of outer col container
[image]
This is what I expected

This is what I am getting

[image]

```css
.content {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  
}
.adventure-card-image {
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="content">
          <!-- TOOD: MODULE_ADVENTURE_DETAILS -->
          <!-- 1. Write the child elements as required. -->
          <!-- 2. Remember to use .adventure-card and its related classes. -->
          <div class="row">

            <!--Grid column-->
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 mb-4">
      
              <img src="/assets/adventures/resort/resort1.jpg" 
              class="adventure-card-image img-fluid mb-4" alt="Resort1">
            </div>
            <!--Grid column-->
      
            <!--Grid column-->
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
      
              <img src="/assets/adventures/resort/resort2.jpg" 
              class="adventure-card-image img-fluid mb-4" alt="Resort2">
      
              <img src="/assets/adventures/resort/resort3.jpg" 
              class="adventure-card-image img-fluid mb-4" alt="Resort3">
      

      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Please provide working snippet

Comment: did you clear the cache? also show the css property of img tag. using code inspector.

Comment: please use placeholder image instead of broken link.

Answer (score 1):

Keep your right side two images into 2 separate **Divs**

Code below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
  .content {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  
}
.adventure-card-image {
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 

  <div class="container">
      <div class="content">
        <!-- TOOD: MODULE_ADVENTURE_DETAILS -->
        <!-- 1. Write the child elements as required. -->
        <!-- 2. Remember to use .adventure-card and its related classes. -->
        <div class="row">
          <!--Grid column-->
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12">
    
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/vga" 
            class="adventure-card-image img-fluid p-3" alt="Resort1">
          </div>
          <!--Grid column-->
    
          <!--Grid column-->
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
            <div>
              <img src="https://dummyimage.com/vga" 
            class="adventure-card-image img-fluid p-3" alt="Resort2">
            </div>
            <div>
              <img src="https://dummyimage.com/vga" 
            class="adventure-card-image img-fluid p-3" alt="Resort3">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```